# when use hard refresh (ctrl+f5) get error in angularjs and requirejs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui-router

I have a `angularjs` application , I use `requirejs` to load modules and files all the thing right when I refresh site with `Ctrl+f5` but when I refresh with `f5` I got some error ! is there anybody knows this problem or even seen this problem before ?
I get this error in firefox console

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr

Comment: Can you elaborate more so that we can help you.